# Laravel credential validation not working

Tags: laravel

Hey guys i am new to laravel and i am trying to build a college project. In the signup part i am not able to validate the users password and email. If the credentials are correct it redirects me to previous page just as i want. But if the credentials are wrong then it is not redirecting me to home page but the page just reloads.

Validation function:

```
public function user_register(Request $request){
            $res = false;
            $request->validate([
                "name"=>"required",
                "email"=>"required|email|unique:custom__auths",
                "password"=>"required|min:5|max:12"
            ]);
            $user = new Custom_Auth();
            $user->name=$request->name;
            $user->email=$request->email;
            $user->pasword=$request->password;
            $res = $user->save();
            echo $res;
            if($res==1){
      
                return back()->with('success','you have registered successfully');
            }
            else{
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }
```

table in database:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('custom__auths', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("name");
            $table->string("email")->unique();
            $table->string("password");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Signup view:

```
@extends('Layouts.Master')

@section('content')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/Assets/CSS/Auth.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <div class="container">
   
        <input type="checkbox" id="flip">
        <div class="cover">
          <div class="front">
            <img class="backImg" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/31/07/36/sunset-3120484_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="text">
              <span class="text-1">Helping you grow<br> stronger each day</span>
              <span class="text-2">Let's code together</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <img class="backImg" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/31/07/36/sunset-3120484_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="text">
              <span class="text-1">Complete miles of journey <br> with one step</span>
              <span class="text-2">Let's get started</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forms">
            <div class="form-content">
             
            <div class="signup-form" >
             
              <div class="title">Signup</div>
            <form action="{{route('UserAuth')}}" method="post">
              @csrf
                <div class="input-boxes">
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="button input-box">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
                  </div>
                  <div class="text sign-up-text">Already have an account?<a href="/login" style="color: blue"> Login now</a></div>
                </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I tried to use dd to understand the root cause of problem but unfortunately i am not able to get to the root cause of the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "page reloads" means validation failed but you didn't show the error messages.

From [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic), what happens if `$request->validate()` fails:

"If validation fails during a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response to the previous URL will be generated."

So it automatically redirects back, exactly what you're saying - "page reloads".

I assume you just don't show the validation errors.

Again, from [the same docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors), example how to show them:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The `$errors` variable will automatically be filled from the session.